# Python adding row into dataframe using while loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a dataset like this:

```
    user_id lapsed_date start_date  end_date
0   A123    2020-01-02  2019-01-02  2019-02-02
1   A123    2020-01-02  2019-02-02  2019-03-02
2   B456    2019-10-01  2019-08-01  2019-09-01
3   B456    2019-10-01  2019-09-01  2019-10-01
```

generated by this code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

sample = {'user_id': ['A123','A123','B456','B456'],
        'lapsed_date': ['2020-01-02', '2020-01-02', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-01'],
        'start_date' : ['2019-01-02', '2019-02-02', '2019-08-01', '2019-09-01'],
        'end_date' : ['2019-02-02', '2019-03-02', '2019-09-01', '2019-10-01']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(sample,columns= ['user_id', 'lapsed_date', 'start_date', 'end_date'])

df['lapsed_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['lapsed_date'])
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'])
```

I'm trying to write a function to achieve this:

```
    user_id lapsed_date start_date  end_date
0   A123    2020-01-02  2019-01-02  2019-02-02
1   A123    2020-01-02  2019-02-02  2019-03-02
2   A123    2020-01-02  2019-03-02  2019-04-02
3   A123    2020-01-02  2019-04-02  2019-05-02
4   A123    2020-01-02  2019-05-02  2019-06-02
5   A123    2020-01-02  2019-06-02  2019-07-02
6   A123    2020-01-02  2019-07-02  2019-08-02
7   A123    2020-01-02  2019-08-02  2019-09-02
8   A123    2020-01-02  2019-09-02  2019-10-02
9   A123    2020-01-02  2019-10-02  2019-11-02
10  A123    2020-01-02  2019-11-02  2019-12-02
11  A123    2020-01-02  2019-12-02  2020-01-02
12  B456    2019-10-01  2019-08-01  2019-09-01
13  B456    2019-10-01  2019-09-01  2019-10-01
```

Essentially the function should keep adding row, for each user_id while the max(end_date) is less than or equal to lapsed_date. The newly added row will take previous row's end_date as start_date, and previous row's end_date + 1 month as end_date.

I have generated this function below.

```
def add_row(x):
    while x['end_date'].max() < x['lapsed_date'].max():
        next_month = x['end_date'].max() + pd.DateOffset(months=1)
        last_row = x.iloc[-1]
        last_row['start_date'] = x['end_date'].max()
        last_row['end_date'] = next_month
        return x.append(last_row)
    return x
```

It works with all the logic above, except the while loop doesn't work. So I have to apply this function using this apply command manually 10 times:

```
df = df.groupby('user_id').apply(add_row).reset_index(drop = True)
```

I'm not really sure what I did wrong with the while loop there. Any advice would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What are you passing to add_row as `x`?

Comment: `x` is meant to be the dataframe. Hence I tried doing `df.groupby('user_id').apply(add_row)`. I'm still fairly new to Python :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few reasons your loop did not work, I will explain them as we go!

```
def add_row(x):
    while x['end_date'].max() < x['lapsed_date'].max():
        next_month = x['end_date'].max() + pd.DateOffset(months=1)
        last_row = x.iloc[-1]
        last_row['start_date'] = x['end_date'].max()
        last_row['end_date'] = next_month
        return x.append(last_row)
    return x
```

In the above, you call `return` which returns the result to the code that called the function. This essentially stops your loop from iterating multiple times and returns the result of the first append.

`return x.append(last_row)` Another caveat here is that dataframe.append() does not actually append to the dataframe, you need to call `x = x.append(last_row)`

[Pandas Append](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41234944/7942856)

Secondly, I noted that it may be required to do this over multiple, unique `user_id` rows. Due to this, in the code below, I have split the dataframe into multiple frames, dictated by the total unique `user_id`'s stored in the frame.

Here is how you can get this to work;

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

def add_row(df):

    while df['end_date'].max() < df['lapsed_date'].max():

        new_row = {'user_id': df['user_id'][0],
                   'lapsed_date': df['lapsed_date'].max(),
                   'start_date': df['end_date'].max(),
                   'end_date': df['end_date'].max() + pd.DateOffset(months=1),
                   }

        df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index = True)

    return df ## Note the return is called OUTSIDE of the while loop, ensuring only the final result is returned.


sample = {'user_id': ['A123','A123','B456','B456'],
        'lapsed_date': ['2020-01-02', '2020-01-02', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-01'],
        'start_date' : ['2019-01-02', '2019-02-02', '2019-08-01', '2019-09-01'],
        'end_date' : ['2019-02-02', '2019-03-02', '2019-09-01', '2019-10-01']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(sample,columns= ['user_id', 'lapsed_date', 'start_date', 'end_date'])

df['lapsed_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['lapsed_date'])
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date']) 


ids = df['user_id'].unique()

g = df.groupby(['user_id'])

result = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['user_id', 'lapsed_date', 'start_date', 'end_date'])

for i in ids:
    group = g.get_group(i)
    result = result.append(add_row(group), ignore_index=True)


print(result)
```

1. Split the frames based on unique user id's
2. Create empty data frame to store result in under `result`
3. Iterate over all user_id's
4. Run the same while loop, ensuring that df is updated with the append rows
5. Return the result and print

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for thorough explanation! I'm going to try this!

Comment: It may be better to `concat` in order to create the result DataFrame than repeatedly append.

Comment: Also that for loop is strange. I’m pretty sure you can just iterate over the result of `groupby` and get the ids and groups that way.