# can't append 1 dataframe to another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

OK i've made some progress....

def A1(coef_comp):
    coef_comp = coef_comp.append(coef_data)

```
print(coef_comp) #print 1
```

print(coef_comp) #print 2

This print function gives the right output I'm looking for....

but I still does not get out of the def function? meaning print 2 still gives me the empty dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append to Series in python/pandas not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234822/append-to-series-in-python-pandas-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

Note that [`append()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) is not an in-place operation. Therefore, you have to assign the result to a variable in case you want to use it later on (e.g. in order to print it out).

---

The following should do the trick:

```
combined_df = coef_comp.append(coef_data)
print(combined_df)
```

Comment: Thank you, Giorgos. As I am trying to append multiple of these coef_data DataFrames into coef_comp in a def loop, how should I go about doing it? I tried coef_comp = coef_comp.append(coef_data) but that did not work

Comment: Stranger still, other parts of the same def function have other identical DataFrame appends but only this one does not work.

Comment: @PythNoob Not all pandas operations come with in-place functionality. You can check the documentation - Usually all the functions that allow in place operations, come with a `inplace` keyword argument (that defaults to `False`)

Comment: OK i've made some progress....

def A1(coef_comp):
    coef_comp = coef_comp.append(coef_data)

    print(coef_comp) #print 1

print(coef_comp) #print 2

This print function gives the right output I'm looking for....

but I still does not get out of the def function? meaning print 2 still gives me the empty dataframe

Comment: @PythNoob Make sure to `return` the result.

Comment: meaning like this?

def A1(coef_comp): 

    coef_comp = coef_comp.append(coef_data) 

    print(coef_comp) #print 1 
    return(coef_comp)
print(coef_comp) #print 2

Comment: Oh I got it. Thank you for the guidance!